# Bind child views to a container by a computed property in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have two containers for elements that are in "Mode 1" or "Mode 2". These modes are an attribute on my Project model (an integer called "mode" that is either 1 or 2).

I want to be able to render my Project views so that they are in the correct container. When I change the project mode on the UI, I want that project to be automatically moved to the appropriate container.

Is there a way to achieve this using Ember.ContainerView? Sorry I don't have any code, I haven't really seen anything that will do this so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two computed properties (linked with controller model mode) on controller. Every will contain filtered by 'mode' array of projects. And than render that arrays on a different containers. So when project mode will change it will be rerendered on other container. My code sample http://jsbin.com/EMIHuwIV/4/edit